# Коли праслов'янський звук "ѣ" (ять) в українській мові трансформувався в "і"?

Tags: історія-мови

Як наші пращури читали літеру "**ѣ**" в пам'ятках, написаних на теренах сучасної України у 9-12 століттях? Я так розумію, що з 12 сторіччя вже з'явився *київський ізвод* і до 18 сторіччя "ѣ" читалася як "і", а що було до 12 сторіччя?

Comment: Авторе, будь ласка, уточніть запитання. Ять — це не звук, а літера. А звуки, які нею записувалися, могли бути різними — в один і той самий час на різних територіях, або навіть на одній території у різні часи

Comment: @bytebuster, про це й питання. Сучасні українці вимовляють *ѣ* здебільшого як *і*, сучасні росіяни як *є*, сучасні болгари як *я* або як росіяни. Коли остаточно сформувалася вимова літери *ѣ* українцями і що було до того.

Comment: @Sasha, у тім-то й справа, що нема такого явища, як «вимова літери ѣ». Є явище — конвенція запису звуку `X` за допомогою символу `Y`.

Comment: @bytebuster, не зрозумів.

Answer (score 4):

[Історична фонологія української мови](//chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Sheveliov_Yurii/Istorychna_fonolohiia_ukrainskoi_movy/)  [(Юрій Шевельов)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) ¬ § 13. Потрактування **ě** (в т. ч. § 13.7).

---

Розвиток звуків літери **ѣ** в українській мові виглядає дещо таким чином:

### <sub>e</sub>ā > <sub>e</sub>a > <sub>i</sub>e > <sub>i</sub>ė > ė

Шевельов також вважає привабливою гіпотезу про те, що можна побудувати узагальнене представлення лінії розвитку цього звуку відразу для декількох мов (а не лише для української; мовляв, цей процес відбувався схоже в українській, російській, білоруській, польській, словацькій і болгарській мовах, але в українській зайшов найдалі, а в інших наразі перебуває на попередніх етапах). Пропонована спільна еволюція цього звуку виглядає таким чином:

### <sub>e</sub>ā > <sub>e</sub>a > ’ȧ > ’æ > ’e > ’ė > ’i

Але врешті-решт за сукупністю аргументів Шевельов сам відмовляється від цієї гіпотези, схиляючись до побудови окремої лінії для української мови (що наведена першою).

---

Така зміна також має назву [**ікавізм**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC)

---

Найдавнішим відтворенням **[ě]** як **[і]** дехто вважає написання *τζερν**ι**γωγαν* (форма зн. відм. від *Черн**і**гів* ← д.‑р. *Черн**ѣ**говъ*) в Костянтина Багрянородного, яке належить середині **10 ст**. Як бачимо, літера **ι** відповідає наголошеному **ě**. На думку [Леоніда Булаховського](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B4_%D0%90%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), таке написання дає право вважати, що принаймні з 10 ст. місто Чернігів населяли «ікавці» — «ієкавці», тобто звук **[ě]** вимовляли як **[і]** або **[іє]**. Проте наведене свідчення дуже ненадійне, щоб на його підставі можна було робити якісь висновки.

Написання **и** замість **ѣ** давньоруські памʼятки південного походження засвідчують декількома прикладами і **в 11 ст.**: *ници**и**, в вѣр**и**, н**и**маѩ, исц**и**ли, въ м**и**роу, двѣ риз**и***. Але поряд із ними в тих самих рукописах засвідчено більше прикладів написання саме з **е** замість **ѣ**: *н**є**сть, в**є**руѫ, л**є**та, нєд**є**лѣ, гн**є**въ*. Звичайно, що навіть такі приклади дають змогу зрозуміти якісну, артикуляційно-акустичну близкість **[ě]** до **[е]** та **[і]**, на що вказують і зворотні процеси заміни: *ѩвлєн**ѣ**ѥ* замість *ѩвлєн**и**ѥ*, *пр**ѣ**вєдуть* замість *пр**и**ведуть*, *утопл**ѣ**нъ* замість *утопл**є**нъ*. **Починаючи з 13 — 14 ст.**, писемні памʼятки засвідчують написання **и** замість **ѣ** вже дуже часто, хоч коли-не-коли й писано **є** замість **ѣ**. Однак вже принаймні з другої половини **13 ст**. в більшості південних говорах давньоруської мови (ареал утворення української мови) звук **[ě]** вимовлявся як монофтонґ **[і]**.

Comment: Я не зрозумів, що означає «в загальних рисах (не тільки української) й менш вагомим розвиток ѣ виглядає так», прочитав першоджерело і спробував роз'яснити Вашу відповідь. Сподіваюсь, Ви не проти (якщо ні, відхиліть, я не проти, зроблю тоді окремо/коментар). І дуже дякую за те, що Ви знайшли цю інформацію.

Comment: Власна, НМД, це найкраща відповідь, бо, хоч інші і наводять цікаву інформацію, але ця єдина, що конкретно відповідає на питання «що було до 12 сторіччя».

Answer (score 3):

Читала, що вимова звуку, записуваного з допомогою «ѣ», розділилася на *і* на *є* близько X століття. (Якщо так неправильно висловлюватися, то я б це назвала «як *вѣра* стала *віра* на одних територіях і *вєра* на інших», а якщо хочеться уявити собі звучання *вѣра*, то з тих двох треба вивести середнє).

Донедавна вважала, що це було у «[Походженні слов'янської писемності](http://prima.lnu.edu.ua/slavistyka/n54/023.pdf)» Брайчевського, але перечитала і не побачила. Тому сама шукаю джерело :(

Comment: Будь ласка, завжди додавайте джерела до тверджень, які містяться у дописах. Тим більше, якщо це стосується  історичних подій.

Answer (score 3):

Є хороша книга на тему української транслітерації церковно-слов'янських текстів Ганни Куземської, яка є у вільному доступі: [Якою мовою молилася давня Україна: Правила української транслітерації церковнослов’янських текстiв](https://parafia.org.ua/biblioteka/knygy-broshury/pravyla-ukrajinskoji-transliteratsiji-suchasnoji-tserkovnoslovyanskoji-movy/) Там є потрібний вам розділ:

> - Лiтеру **ѣ** транслiтерують переважно як i: **вѣршъ** /вiрш/, **гнѣвъ**
>     /гнiв/, **человѣкъ** /человiк/, **стрѣлы** /стрiли/, **вѣтрыло** /вiтрило/, **вѣрꙋю**
>     /вiрую/, **посѣща́єши** /посiщаєши/, **вѣвцѣ** /вiвцi/ тощо.
> - **ѣ** пишуть як ї пiсля голосної, префiксiв або на початку слова
>     (зазвичай у нашiй лiтературнiй мовi ХVI–ХIХ ст.): **мωѣ** /мої/, **то́ѣж**
>     /тої ж/, **мно́гіѣ** /многiї/, **до збавенноѣ, ꙋторованоѣ дороги** /до
>     збавенної, уторованої дороги/; **отъѣзжій** /от’їзжий/; **ѣжъ** /їж/ тощо.
>
> *Виняток. У текстах ХI–ХIII ст. лiтера **ѣ** може звучати як **е**, **а** чи **я**:
>   **прѣжде** /прежде/, **благодѣть** /благодать/, **времѣ** /врем’я/, **имѣх** /iм’яху/
>   тощо.*